# spring boot actuator/refresh does not refresh custom properties defined in bootstrap.properties using liberty server

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, refresh, websphere-liberty, spring-boot-actuator

I have a microservice that runs using the liberty server. I have set of configuration properties that are not being used directly using @Value or @ConfigurationProperties or @Configuration.

Properties Structure:

I have application.yml as

```
DBUserName: ${username}
DBPassword: ${password}
```

and bootstrap.properties as

```
username: XXXX
password: XXXX
```

now I have implemented a config server and it is reading property file from the git repo. Config file structure:

appname-dev.yml

```
Username: abcd
password: abcd
```

In the client, I have configured bootstrap.yml as

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  application:
    name: appname
  cloud:
    bootstrap:
      enabled: true
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

Whenever I update the properties in the git repo, the config server gets the updated properties but client-side those properties are not getting updated after hitting actuator/refresh endpoint.

When I hit actuator/env at the client-side, it displays the updated properties from the config server but bootstrap.properties will have the same old properties which application uses.

So, what am I missing here? will the config server not work for this scenario?

Comment: What is the client code? Maybe the problem is there?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this will work. The word application has to be first then the profile. So `application-bootstrap.yml`, if that is the name you really want. Dont forget to set the profile `bootstrap`.

Comment: application.yml properties are getting replaced by bootstrap.properties file when application gets loaded the first time. I am using the IBM liberty server here. Now at run time, I want to update username and password values which I have kept in the git repo. Git repo file name is appname-dev.yml where dev is the profile name and the appname is the application name.

Comment: @reeteshkumar are you sure. Double check by adding a string to `bootstrap.properties` and log the log.info(testString); in the application with @Value("${testString}). If it doesn't work try renaming to what I suggested.

Comment: I am not using these properties directly with @Value.  That is why I have mentioned this in the question. So these are custom properties not directly being used in service, controller, or configuration class. My explanation seems confusing but this the use case.